# Django & Js : use cleaned_data instead of request.POST on simple HTML inputs

Tags: javascript, django, forms, data-cleaning

i've created a form in forms.py , and after submiting the form, the values are inserted in my database smoothly, using `form.cleaned_data`.
  [image]
my template has a button (called : "ajouter une ligne") that adds a new line (the line contains a form similar to the original one). this action (of adding line) is coded by Js.

[image]
my problem is ,when i want to submit the final form that contains the original line and the second . it only submits the first one, because the first ligne is created on forms.py so on submition it's submited with clean_data . However the second line is created on the template using js directly so `form.cleaned_data` doesn't work on it.

here is my template original row :

```
<form action="/veentes"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% 
 csrf_token %}{{ form.non_field_errors }}
 <table style ="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 15px;" id="div1">
<tr><td width="5%">N P</td><td width="25%">Désignation</td><td width="8%">Date de Facture</td><td width="10%">Montant HT</td><td width="10%">TVA</td><td width="10%">Montant TTC</td></tr>

     <tr style="border:1px solid black;" >

        <td><div class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">1</p></b></div></td>

        <td>
            {% render_field form.designation1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="désignation" name="designation1" %}{{form.degn.errors}}

        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.datefacture1  class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Date de Facture" name="datefacture1" %}{{form.dateFac.errors}}

        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.mht1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Montant HT" name="mht1" %}{{form.mht.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% render_field form.mtva1 class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="TVA" name="mtva1" %}{{form.mtva.errors}}
        </td>
        <td>{% render_field form.mttc1 class="form-control" 
         id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Montant TTC" name="mttc1" %}
         {{form.mttc.errors}}
        </td>
        </form>



</tr>
```

here is my Js Code that creats the new row :

```
var click=1;
function addform() {
click +=1;
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
//create a tr
var id_tr="tr"+click;
create_tr(element, id_tr);
document.getElementById('num').value=click;

//create inputs 
var designation = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(designation, "text" , "designation", "form-control", 
"Désignation",click);

var datef = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(datef, "date" , "datefacture", "form-control", "Date de 
Facture",click);

var mht = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mht, "text" , "mht", "form-control", "Montant HT",click);

var mtva = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mtva, "text" , "mtva", "form-control", "Montant TVA",click);

var mttc = document.createElement("INPUT");
textinput(mttc, "text" , "mttc", "form-control", "Montant TTC",click);



var elmtr=document.getElementById(id_tr);
var y = document.createElement("TD");
var td="td";
 td=td + id_tr;
y.setAttribute("id", td+0);
elmtr.appendChild(y);
var elmtd=document.getElementById(td+0);
var x = document.createElement("B");
x.setAttribute("name","np"+click);
x.setAttribute("class","col-xs-1");
var t = document.createTextNode(click);
x.appendChild(t);
elmtd.appendChild(x);
create_tds(elmtr, designation, 1 ,id_tr);
create_tds(elmtr, datef, 2 ,id_tr);
create_tds(elmtr, mht, 4 ,id_tr);
create_tds(elmtr, mtva, 5,id_tr);
create_tds(elmtr, mttc, 6 , id_tr);


 }
function create_tr(element, id_tr){
 var trr = document.createElement("TR");
 trr.setAttribute("id", id_tr);
 element.appendChild(trr);

 }
 function create_tds(elmtr,input_td, clicktd,id_tr){
  var y = document.createElement("TD");
  var td="td";
  td=td + id_tr;
  y.setAttribute("id", td+clicktd);
  elmtr.appendChild(y);
  var elmtd=document.getElementById(td+clicktd);
  elmtd.appendChild(input_td);

  }
function textinput(x, type, name, classe, placeholder,click){

x.setAttribute("type", type);
x.setAttribute("name", name+click);
x.setAttribute("class", classe);
x.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholder);
if (name=="file") {

    x.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
if (type == "button") {
x.setAttribute("value", "importer");    
}
 }
```

my views Code is :

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        p=int(request.POST['numpiece'])
        print(p)
        np=p
        form=FormVents(request.POST,request.FILES)
        #np=1
        print("numpiece")
        np=2
        x=client.objects.all().filter(nom=request.POST['client_name']).values_list('id', flat=True)
        if form.is_valid():
            for j in range(1,np+1):
                print(j)
                 vent=ventes(numpiece=j,id_facture_id=v.id,designation=form.cleaned_data.get('designation'+str(j)),montantHT=form.cleaned_data.get('mht'+str(j)),montantTVA=form.cleaned_data.get('mtva'+str(j)),montantTTC=form.cleaned_data.get('mttc'+str(j)))
                vent.save()
    else:
        form = forms.FormVents(request.POST or None)
```

form.py :

```
class FormVents(forms.Form):
    designation1=forms.CharField()
    datefacture1=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    mht1=forms.FloatField()
    mtva1=forms.FloatField()
    mttc1=forms.FloatField()
```

Please any ideas , how can i use `cleaned_data` on my second line too? 
PS: when i replace `form.cleaned_data` with `request.POST` it adds both lines, but i want to add all my lines using cleaned_data because i read that for data security i need to work with form.cleaned_data.
So please help me resolve this . Thank You So much

Comment: Two possible problems with the html. You may have two items with the same id and you may have two inputs with the same name. You can either manually change the form input id's and name attributes or you can use formsets like GwynBleidD suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) in Django. They allow to submit multiple objects in bulk. You can create it to be based on your existing form:

```
class FormVents(forms.Form):
    designation1=forms.CharField()
    datefacture1=forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    mht1=forms.FloatField()
    mtva1=forms.FloatField()
    mttc1=forms.FloatField()

VentsFormSet = formset_factory(FormVents)
```

And then, in your view, you can use it almost exactly like normal form. Only difference is that you will need to iterate over your formset to extract data for each object:

```
formset = VentsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset:
        data_to_be_saved = form.cleaned_data
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i see what you're saying but i cant see on my template how can i let the button "ajouter une ligne" , add a new row depending on the VentsFormSet created on forms.py ?

Comment: You need to update `form-TOTAL_FORMS` hidden field in your HTML form (this field will be created by using `{{ formset.management_form }}` in your template. Of course, you have to add formset to your template context). Formset will pick up that number and process that many forms from response.

Comment: okey i will do so, and update you if it's solved. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: i get 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' error , even if i've added {{ formset.management_form }} to my template

Comment: Please, create new question with that issue or find one that already answers it. And check with debugger in browser that this inputs are present in template and are sent with request.